# Assembly sorting

Tags: sorting, assembly, mips

I am working on a Task Schedule Simulator which needs to be programmed in Assembly language. 
I've been struggling about Task sorting:

I am allocating new memory for each Task (user can insert the task and by using the sbrk instruction i allocate 20 byte that contain a word for Task's numeric ID, another word for it's priority expressed as an int, another word for the number of cycles to finish the task) and I'm storing the address of each new Task in the stack.

My problem is: i need to sort this tasks and the sorting can either be based on priority or number of cycles. When I pop these Tasks i can easily access the right field (since the structure is very rigid, i just need to type the right offset in the lw instruction and voilat), but then comparing and sorting gets complicated.

I am working on the pseudocode for this part of the program and can't find any way to untie the knot.

Comment: Can you post your code and pseudocode to take a look at it?

Comment: How does the number of cycles affect priority? Since this is a scheduler question, how many tasks can run at the same time? As for the sort, an array or linked list would be easier to sort than a stack.

Comment: Thank you all for answering so quickly. I will post code ASAP - not at home right now.
The number of cycles affects priority if user decides to sort the tasks by number of cycles. In that case, the task with the lowest number of cycles is the first to be executed. The program can run one single task at the time.

Comment: For a complex problem like this, it's always easier to write pseudo-code in C and hand compile it into assembler.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first try and paraphrase what you have indicate as the problem.
You have a stack, that has "records" of the structure

{ word : id, word : priority, word : cycle_count, dword : address}

Since the end objective is to "pop" these in desired order, we have to execute an in-place sort. There are many choices of algorithms, but to keep matters simple (also taking a cue from an underlying assumption that the count of tasks is not that many), I am explaining using bubble-sort. There exist a vast cornucopia of literature comparing each probable sort algorithm to their finest details, and if relevant, you may consider wikipedia as the perfect starting point.

Step 1 : Make the data pointer = stack pointer+count_of_records*20 - effectively, for next few steps, the data pointer points to the top of the "table of records" which happens to be located at the stack. An advanced consideration but not required in MIPS, is to assert DS=SS.

Step 2 : Next, identify which record pair needs to be swapped, and use the appropriate index within a record to identify the field that defines the swapping order.

Step 3: Allocate a 20 byte space as temporary, and use that space to temporarily hold the swapped record. An advanced consideration here is whether the environment can do an interrupt while the swap is going on. MIPS does not seem to have an atomic lock so this memory move needs to be carefully done.

Once the requisite number of passes are completed, the table will appear sorted, and will remain in place. The temporary buffer to store a record may be released.

The vital statistics for Bubble-Sort is that its O(n^2), responds well to almost sorted situations (not very likely in your example), and will handle the fact well that in midst of sorting, some records may find the processor free to start running, and therefore, will have to be removed from the queue by a POP and the sort needs to be restarted. This restart, however, will find the table almost sorted, and therefore, on a continuous basis, the table will display fairly strong pre-sorted behavior. Most importantly, has the perhaps most efficient code footprint among all *in-situ* algorithms.

Trust this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to introduce a level of indirection, and sort pointers to your structs based on comparing the pointed-to data.

If your sort keys are all integers of the same size at different offsets within the structs, your sort function could take an offset as a parameter.  e.g. `lw` from `base + off` to get the integer that you're going to compare.

---

Insertion sort is probably easiest to code, and much better that BubbleSort in the not-almost-sorted case.  If you care about having a result ready to pop ASAP, before the whole array is sorted, then use [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

It wasn't clear if your code is itself going to be multi-threaded, or if you can just write a normal sort function.  @qasar66's answer seems to be suggesting a BubbleSort with atomic swaps, so other threads can safely look at the partially-sorted array while its being sorted.

---

If you only ever need to pop the min element, one of the best data structures is a [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).  It takes more code to implement, so if ease of implementation is your top goal, use a simple sort.  Heapifying an un-sorted array is cheaper than doing a full sort: the full O(n log n) cost of extracting all elements in order is amortized over the extracts.  So it's great if you want to be able to change the sort key, since you don't have to do all the work of fully sorting.